# Transfer Bitcoin to Google Wallet

Tags: money-transfer

I need to pay someone who doesn't use Bitcoin. I don't use paypal.

Is it possible to create a Google wallet and add Bitcoin to the balance? I have seen conflicting answers. I believe you cannot do it directly but I have seen sites that claim to give you $1.5 in Google Wallet money for each $1 in BTC you trade.

Is there a safe way to do this or another method?

Answer (score 1):

Google Wallet does not support bitcoin.

You could send him PayPal and then he could use https://xcoins.io to convert into Bitcoin.

Or you could purchase Bitcoin with Paypal from https://xcoins.io and then send the Bitcoin you purchased to his Bitcoin wallet address.

Another option if you're not in a rush is to use https://coinbase.com but buys are not instant for new users as far as I know.

The only reason I recommend xCoins is because you said PayPal and Bitcoin.. and xCoins is the quickest way to get Bitcoin.

NOTE: I work for xCoins as a engineer.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear. I have Bitcoin but the seller does not. I was wondering if there was a way to get a google wallet balance if I have Bitcoin. E.g. could I pay someone in BTC and they send money to my Google wallet?

Comment: If he knows nothing about Bitcoin your best bet may be Payza. But its tough to send Bitcoin to a non-bitcoin user :/

Comment: Your best bet would to be withdraw bitcoin and send it in fiat currency. It would be like sending a caveman money and they wouldn't know what to do ;p

Comment: This answer looks like an advertisement, the xcoins link is referral.

Comment: NOTE: I work for xCoins (look at my profile). I would recommend them over any other service like coinbase or gemini.